# How to get value from another class's inside of if-else statements?

Tags: c#, class, variables, if-statement

When I call `dnanumber` variable from another class it seems `0` in console. How can I fix this problem?

```
class DNAgenerator
    {



        public int dnanumber;



        public int dna;
        public int dna2;
        public int dna3;
        public int dna4;



        public void generetor()
        {

            Random user = new Random();

            dna = user.Next(1,41);
            dna2 = user.Next(1,41);
            dna3 = user.Next(1, 41);
            dna4 = user.Next(1, 41);

            Random nukleodite = new Random();



            if (dna == nukleodite.Next(1,11))
            {            
                dnanumber = 65;
            }

              else if(dna== nukleodite.Next(11, 21))
            {

                dnanumber = 67;
             }
             else if (dna == nukleodite.Next(21, 31))
                {

                dnanumber = 71;
             }
           else if(dna == nukleodite.Next(31,41))
            {

                dnanumber = 84;
            }


            //   dna2   

            if (dna2 == nukleodite.Next(1, 11))
            {
                dnanumber = 65;
            }

            else if (dna2 == nukleodite.Next(11, 21))
            {
                dnanumber = 67;
            }
            else if (dna2 == nukleodite.Next(21, 31))
            {
                dnanumber = 71;
            }
            else if (dna2 == nukleodite.Next(31, 41))
            {
                dnanumber = 84;
            }


            //dna3


            if (dna3 == nukleodite.Next(1, 11))
            {

            }

            else if (dna3 == nukleodite.Next(11, 21))
            {

            }
            else if (dna3 == nukleodite.Next(21, 31))
            {

            }
            else if (dna3 == nukleodite.Next(31, 41))
            {

            }


            //dna4

            if (dna4 == nukleodite.Next(1, 11))
            {

            }

            else if (dna4 == nukleodite.Next(11, 21))
            {

            }
            else if (dna4 == nukleodite.Next(21, 31))
            {

            }
            else if (dna4 == nukleodite.Next(31, 41))
            {

            }

        }
   }


static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            DNAgenerator user = new DNAgenerator();




            user.generetor();







            Console.WriteLine(user.dna.ToString() + " " +user.dna2.ToString() + " " + user.dna3.ToString() + " " + user.dna4.ToString() );




            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer the question. Where is `dnanumber` defined? What is it's value before these `if` statements? What "other class" are you referring to? Which line of code is problematic? Presumably none of your `if` conditions evaluated to `true`, so `dnanumber` remains at the default value of `0`?

Comment: dnanumber declared  above of DNAgenerator method and it has no value.And other class is main class (static void main) and i created object inside it to call dnanumber.

Comment: You need to show more of the code here, like where `dnanumber` is defined in the class and how you are creating the class/referencing it in the main program class.

Comment: You need to show the code that's not working, please. It provides full context and will show where a problem may occur. In the meantime, are you certain that one of the `if` conditions above evaluates to `true`? Because if not, then of course `dnanumber` will have the default value of an integer (`0`).

Comment: I updated it please check again